# PDF export from print layout is smaller than page size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to export a map to a 1132x1132 px pdf.
Here are the steps I followed:

- create a new print layout with a custom 1132x1132 px page size
  [image]
- add the map and define *Position and Size** properties
  [image]

The expected behaviour would be to get a 1132x1132 px pdf when doing so with the *Export as PDF* button from the print layout. Instead the pdf is 272x272px.

**Why is it so and how can I export a 1132x1132 px pdf document ?**

I am using QGIS3.4 Madeira.